# Laravel 4.0 nested controller

Tags: routes, laravel, controllers, laravel-4

I try to get the nested controller in Laravel 4 based on the following structure:

- app

  - controllers

    - base

      - BaseController.php
    - website

      - WebsiteController.php

I want to get the website route to be associated with WebsiteController that extend BaseController.

I've try the following thing

**for route.php**
(*app/route.php*)

```
Route::resource('website', 'Controllers\Website\WebsiteController');
```

**for BaseController.php**
(*app/controllers/base/BaseController.php*)

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller;
class BaseController extends Controller {

    protected function setupLayout(){
        if ( ! is_null($this->layout)){
            $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
        }
    }
}
```

**for WebsiteController.php**
(*app/controllers/website/WebsiteController.php*)

```
use Controllers\Base\BaseController;
class WebsiteController extends BaseController {
    public function index(){
        return 'index';
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when i go to http://mywebsite.com/website it's not working at all.

Thank you.

Comment: Erreur HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a stack trace or related message you can print out here as well?

Comment: Don't get any error neither any log error.

Comment: I'm not sure what OS you're on, but my next strategy at getting a meaningful error message would be to check the web-server error logs

Comment: good Idea for the logs @fideloper.

It's working now. ( i'll post the result )

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a error dump, we can't know for sure, but you can try these:

1) Run composer's dump-autoload, so the auto-loader knows of the new classes:

```
$ php composer.phar dump-autoload
```

2) I don't believe you need to use the `use Controllers\Base\BaseController` directives as the models directory is auto-loaded by default. Since you're not name-spacing your controllers differently, the `use` directive shouldn't be needed. The above 'dump-autoload' should do the trick

3) After the dump-autoload, change

```
Route::resource('website', 'Controllers\Website\WebsiteController');
```

to this:

```
Route::resource('website', 'WebsiteController');
```

You use of specific classes (for instance 'Controllers\Website\WebsiteController') won't be necessary unless you define a different namespace for your new controllers

Comment: event with a dump-autoload and changing the route it still don't work.


I've simplify the code by extending websitecontroller with Controller ( removing the baseController step )

But event like that it's still show error 500